# Firebase Ui not show data in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Im try to show in fragment not show data but i can on activity

I'm use as same code from [Firebase UI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md) not sure what i forget it 
and

Here my data in firebase

[image]

My result i get

[image]

Heire my code

SOS.Fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_sos, container, false);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_report);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(shared_preferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.rv_sos);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());


    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();



    mBtn = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.s_o_s_btn);
    mBtn.setOnClickListener(this);


                mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<SOS, SoSViewHolder>
                        (
                                SOS.class,
                                R.layout.sos_list,
                                SoSViewHolder.class,
                                mRef.child("report")
                        )
                {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(SoSViewHolder holder, SOS sos, int position) {
                        holder.setMtopic(sos.getRpTitle());
                        holder.setMlocation(sos.getRpLocation());
                    }
                };

                mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    return view;
}
```

SOS Model

```
package com.enovagroup.army3.Model;
```

/**
 * Created by Android Dev on 29/8/2560.
 */
public class SOS {

```
private String rpAddress;
private String rpAuther;
private String rpBody;
private String rpCreate;
private String rpId;
private String rpLocation;
private String rpPic;
private Integer rpTimestamp;
private String rpTitle;

public SOS(){

}

public SOS(String rpAddress, String rpAuther, String rpBody, String rpCreate, String rpId, String rpLocation,
           String rpPic, Integer rpTimestamp, String rpTitle) {
    this.rpAddress = rpAddress;
    this.rpAuther = rpAuther;
    this.rpBody = rpBody;
    this.rpCreate = rpCreate;
    this.rpId = rpId;
    this.rpLocation = rpLocation;
    this.rpPic = rpPic;
    this.rpTimestamp = rpTimestamp;
    this.rpTitle = rpTitle;
}

public void setRpAddress(String rpAddress) {
    this.rpAddress = rpAddress;
}

public void setRpAuther(String rpAuther) {
    this.rpAuther = rpAuther;
}

public void setRpBody(String rpBody) {
    this.rpBody = rpBody;
}

public void setRpCreate(String rpCreate) {
    this.rpCreate = rpCreate;
}

public void setRpId(String rpId) {
    this.rpId = rpId;
}

public void setRpLocation(String rpLocation) {
    this.rpLocation = rpLocation;
}

public void setRpPic(String rpPic) {
    this.rpPic = rpPic;
}

public void setRpTimestamp(Integer rpTimestamp) {
    this.rpTimestamp = rpTimestamp;
}

public void setRpTitle(String rpTitle) {
    this.rpTitle = rpTitle;
}

public String getRpAddress() {
    return rpAddress;
}

public String getRpAuther() {
    return rpAuther;
}

public String getRpBody() {
    return rpBody;
}

public String getRpCreate() {
    return rpCreate;
}

public String getRpId() {
    return rpId;
}

public String getRpLocation() {
    return rpLocation;
}

public String getRpPic() {
    return rpPic;
}

public Integer getRpTimestamp() {
    return rpTimestamp;
}

public String getRpTitle() {
    return rpTitle;
}
```

Sos ViewHolder

```
public class SoSViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

public TextView mtopic , mlocation;
private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
public String rptitle,rpbody,rpauther,rpaddress,rplocation;

public SoSViewHolder(View view) {
    super(view);

    mtopic = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.sos_topic);
    mlocation = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.sos_location);

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), SoSDetail.class);

            intent.putExtra("rp_title",mtopic.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("rp_location",mlocation.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("rp_body",rpbody);
            intent.putExtra("rp_title",rptitle);
            intent.putExtra("rp_address",rpaddress);
            intent.putExtra("rp_auther",rpauther);
            intent.putExtra("rp_location",rplocation);
        }
    });
}

public void setMtopic(String topic){
    mtopic.setText(topic);
}

public void setMlocation(String location){
    mlocation.setText(location);
}
```

I hope everyone can solove my problem im try to any thing to fix my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different naming conventions in your database and code. For example, `rp_auther` vs `rpAuther`. The adapter doesn't know how to map these values, which might be the reason for the empty data.

You can either rename property names in the database or add `@SerializedName("rp_auther")` annotations to your pojo class.